# Type arguments for method can be inferred for 1 but not 2 parameters in method call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a helper method to Generate a DropDown for MVC I've dabbled a bit with expressions and reflection and have been able to get the following to work:

```
public static DropDown GenerateDropDown<TSource, TProperty>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> text,
            Expression<Func<TSource, object>> value,
            string selectedValue = "",
            string placeholder = "") where TSource : class
        {
...
return new DropDown(...);
}
```

I can than use the following code to generate a DropDown

```
DropDown.GenerateDropDown(routes, r => r.Name, r => r.Id, selectedValue, "Please Select One");
```

This uses type inference to gather data on what the list (IEnumerable) will be and helps us determine which properties should be used as the Text and the Value, Name and Id respectively.

Note the above code works! However I don't like using `object` as the second type parameter for the `Expression<Func<TSource, object>> value` parameter (it doesn't give good intellisense).  But when I change it to `Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> value` (just like the parameter above it), I get the error below:

```
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'DropDown.GenerateDropDown<TSource, TProperty>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>>, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>>, string, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Why is this happening?  How is it possible to have 1 working but when adding/changing to 2 it fails?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the data types of `r.Name` and `r.Id`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry I fail to see what the data types matter, but Name is a string and Id is a decimal.

Comment: `TProperty` cannot refer to 2 different things - you could try `GenerateDropDown<TSource, TProperty1, TProperty2>` and `Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty1>> text, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty2>> value,` but its unclear what the point of this is

Comment: Since you appear to be wanting to generate a `<select>` element, then tis is definitely not the way to do it and I recommend you study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs). If on the other hand, you want to generate just the options (i.e. `IEnumerable><SelectListItem>`, then your last 2 parameters make no sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke your first comment was spot on, thanks!

Comment: My second comment is far more important :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke haha, I simply built a helper method for something someone else in my company made and I was pretty certain the actual implementation inside the function wasn't the issue so I left it out.  Could it be better, probably, but it does what we need for now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136499/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tyler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Name is a string and Id is a decimal.

The type of `TProperty` must be the same type for the entire method, you can't have it represent one data type in one location and a different data type in a different location. If you want to have separate data types you need 3 generic types in the declaration.

```
public static DropDown GenerateDropDown<TSource, TName, TValue>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Expression<Func<TSource, TName>> text,
            Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> value,
            string selectedValue = "",
            string placeholder = "") where TSource : class
{
    ...
    return new DropDown(...);
}
```

Note, if `text` will always be returned a string you could change your code to

```
public static DropDown GenerateDropDown<TSource, TProperty>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Expression<Func<TSource, string>> text,
            Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> value,
            string selectedValue = "",
            string placeholder = "") where TSource : class
        {
...
return new DropDown(...);
}
```

too

Comment: You are a genius!

Answer (score 5):

A pertinent comment:

> What are the data types of r.Name and r.Id?

Your response:

> Sorry I fail to see what the data types matter, but Name is a string and Id is a decimal.

It is your failure to see why it matters that explains why you are confused by the error.  (In general you should **never believe that types don't matter when your question is about type inference.** Types are the only thing that matters in type inference!)

With your change you require that `TProperty` be inferred to be *both* `string` and `decimal`.  When faced with this problem, C# does not say "the only base type common to string and decimal is object" and infer object.  Rather, C# says "this guy thinks that strings and decimals are the same thing, and therefore the program is probably a bug".  Choosing object would be the wrong thing to do here.

The rule in C# for type inference is that (1) bounds are determined on each type parameter, and then (2) a *best* type **chosen from the type bounds** is picked.  C# never "magics up" a new best type. It never says, "hey, you want this thing to be both Dog and Cat, and therefore it must be Animal".  It says "you wish me to choose between Dog and Cat, and neither is better".

Now, if asked to choose between Dog and Animal, then one is clearly better: the more general type Animal is chosen. But the type that is chosen is *from the set of things to be chosen from*, always.

You can see this in many other places in C#:

```
var x = new[] { dog, cat };
```

That's an error, not an array of animals. But

```
var x = new [] { dog, (Animal)cat };
```

is an array of animals.

Comment: Cool thanks! It was my misunderstanding of Expressions, I was looking at both expressions as returning to me a `Type` (which is exactly what I'm using them for in the end), but it's clearly more than that.